# RedisInsights unable to connect to redis cluster

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I am trying to connect my RedisInsightsv2 client to a cluster of redis instances.

When the redis instance hasn't joined the cluster yet, redisinsights is able to make a connection.
After the cluster is created however, new connections from the GUI, just fail.

I have 3 shards with 1 replica each:

```
redis-cli -h 10.9.9.4 -p 7001 --cluster create 10.9.9.4:7001 10.9.9.5:7002 10.9.9.6:7003 10.9.9.4:7004 10.9.9.5:7005 10.9.9.6:7006 --cluster-replicas 1 -a Password
```

The cluster gets successfully created with the right shards and everything.

I can even verify using the `CLUSTER NODES` command

```
root ➜ ~ $ redis-cli -h 10.9.9.4 -p 7004 -a Password
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
10.9.9.4:7004> CLUSTER NODES
5b77b776f0ed08b4f34b0fe3e48b609e4bd8400e 10.9.9.6:7003@17003 master - 0 1662318446553 3 connected 10923-16383
a42f44163b046273ca02b1fc99ed93cf6188f65e 10.9.9.5:7002@17002 master - 0 1662318446755 2 connected 5461-10922
d2b21a37b62283a6cfbd5fb436df505ddc31aea8 10.1.1.10:7001@17001 master - 0 1662318445549 1 connected 0-5460
2cd5783411ceea96b4006b596942cc49484884ab 10.9.9.5:7005@17005 slave d2b21a37b62283a6cfbd5fb436df505ddc31aea8 0 1662318445750 1 connected
61541ad0455539335f27d5a90a5a8e504b3dea5f 10.1.1.11:7004@17004 myself,slave 5b77b776f0ed08b4f34b0fe3e48b609e4bd8400e 0 1662318445000 3 connected
c00d264a625998e89becb9334a1f4ea9d2057a0d 10.9.9.6:7006@17006 slave a42f44163b046273ca02b1fc99ed93cf6188f65e 0 1662318445550 2 connected
10.9.9.4:7004>
```

However, when trying to connect to any of these in the UI I get the following errors:

```
9/4/2022, 12:03:31 PM | ERROR | TimeoutInterceptor | Request Timeout. GET /api/instance/9e253e74-0091-44b8-bf8c-29ff0f4f0275/connect | {"stack":[{}]}
9/4/2022, 12:03:41 PM | ERROR | TimeoutInterceptor | Request Timeout. GET /api/instance/9e253e74-0091-44b8-bf8c-29ff0f4f0275/connect | {"stack":[{}]}
```

**OR**

```
9/4/2022, 12:16:17 PM | ERROR | KeysBusinessService | Failed to get keys with details info. Connection is closed.. | {"stack":[{}]}
9/4/2022, 12:16:18 PM | ERROR | ExceptionsHandler | Connection is closed. | {"stack":[{}]}
9/4/2022, 12:16:23 PM | ERROR | ExceptionsHandler | Connection is closed. | {"stack":[{}]}
```

This is the `redis.conf` that I use for 10.9.9.5:

```
port 7002
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgraph.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redistimeseries.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisbloom.so
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file cluster-node-2.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
dbfilename dump-2.rdb
maxmemory 1862mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
requirepass Password
masterauth Password
```

I've done a bunch of googling but I'm not able to determine why this is failing. Any help is appreciated!

> RedisInsight version: 2.8.0
>
> Running on: Windows 11
>
> Cluster is running on remote machines part of my local network i.e.
> 10.9.9.0/24

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and see if you are able to connect using this debug build: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1od2uClDKb0649ixkgyRwXfqj8QLr0GXw/view?usp=sharing

Also please check and comment the logs if it is not working

Comment: I get this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toJSON')\n    at SettingsOnPremiseService.getSettings (webpack://redisinsight/./redisinsight/api/dist/src/modules/core/providers/settings-on-premise/settings-on-premise.service.js?:58:79)\n    at AutoDiscoveryService.onModuleInit"

Comment: @XChikuX can you try to use this in isolation? Looks like existing settings is causing some issues.

Comment: @XChikuX Is this error shown in the UI?

Comment: The UI just mostly times out @Gnanesh